# I want to query data from mysql table between two dates

Tags: netbeans-platform

I want to query data from mysql table between two dates but my jTable is showing zero results.

Here is my code

```
Connection con = getConnection();
String date1 = jDate1.getDateFormatString();
String date2 = jDate2.getDateFormatString();

Statement st;
ResultSet rs;




try {

String sql = "select * from summary where _date between '"+date1+"' and '"+date2+"' ";
st = con.createStatement();
rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

summaryTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));



}
catch (Exception e)
{
System.out.println(e);
}
}
```

Comment: What class are jDateN ? What is the result of the getDatrFormatString call ? Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: You should use PreparedStatement so the type conversion will be done for you.

Comment: jDate is JDateChooser class